# Linux: How to add a suffix to files maintaining extension

Tags: linux, bash, centos, batch-rename

Linux bash, Centos.

How to add a suffix to files maintaining extension?
I could find answer about how to change or add extension to files but not for how to add suffix maintaining the extension...

For example: If I want to add the '_thumb' suffix to all image files (.jpg, .png, .gif, .JPEG) in some directory.

somefile.jpg -> somefile_thumb.jpg

EDIT: If possible the script can be re-launched and not affect those files which have already been renamed. In order to add more extensions to the list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.jpg *.png *.gif *.JPEG; do
    [[ $f != *_thumb.* ]] && mv "$f" "${f%.*}_thumb.${f##*.}"
done
```

Comment: Many thanks! It runs.
But, one more doubt: If I want to relaunch the script and don't want to rename those files which already have been renamed before? (for example, in order to add some extensions more)

Comment: Check updated answer. It will skip renaming same files next time.

Answer (score 1):

In a slight variation, you can force the removal of only the extension found with:

```
mv "$file" "${file%.${file##*.}}_thumb.${file##*.}"
```

Answer (score 0):

'rename' command is probably what are you looking for:

```
rename 's/^(.*)\.(png|jpg|gif|JPEG)$/$1_thumbnail.$2/' *.png *.jpg *.gif *.JPEG
```

for explanation:

- first argument in quotes means substitution: 's/regex-what-to-find/replacement-string/'
- this regex matches every filename which begins by random string and ends with dot appended by one of listed extensions
- regex parts enclosed in round brackets will store matched substring into variables like $1 and $2 which are used in the replacement-string.
- *.png *.jpg *.gif *.JPEG are only file list, asterisks are expanded by shell to full file-list. You can use only one asterisk there in case you have only images in directory.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.